# MS Botframework Directline v3.0 messageIds repeating - how to make them unique?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We have developed Windows Service that sends messages to [Directline API 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts). Besides [creating new conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation) it uses also [reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation) if the conversation was idle until the token expired.

Lately, we observed duplicated message Ids for messages with different content - see an example of 3 such message Ids from one conversation:

```
EfNI0i891Ic9T0UyK3QbOP|0000001  2017-10-20 08:44:10.133
EfNI0i891Ic9T0UyK3QbOP|0000001  2017-10-23 15:31:20.000
EfNI0i891Ic9T0UyK3QbOP|0000001  2017-10-25 21:33:01.897
```

It looks like the numbering was reset at random time even that the highest message Id of the whole conversation was

```
EfNI0i891Ic9T0UyK3QbOP|0000233
```

Is there some built-in mechanism, 3rd party component or known approach to control creating of message Ids or using "alternative-message-Ids" so that we can make them unique?

Comment: Are you doing your own polling to directline not using the watermark?

Comment: We use watermark as specified at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities We ran across this topic when comparing logs from bot-controller and logs from our client windows service